# generate qrcode with data and encrypted with key

Tags: flutter, qr-code, func

I have to make a view where you see a qrCode. I have to write the function in the project in flutter and since we have the old project on Android Studio in Java, I wanted to try to take a cue from there. in Java the colleague before me encrypts a json containing `(type ": 1," content ": email," display_name "," mac ")` with a key that is passed on the basis of the user and generates the qr that is shown.

i found this flutter library which generates qrcode, qr_flutter
but now how can I integrate it into the part I need? someone quò help me to write the function that generates me the qrcode with those 4 data in the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data needed by `QrImage` widget is a `String` so you could do it like that:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

Widget _buildQrCode() {
  Map<String,dynamic> myData = {
    'type': type,
    'content': content,
    'email': email,
    'mac': mac,
  };

  String encodedJson = jsonEncode(myData);

  return QrImage(
    data: encodedJson,
    version: QrVersions.auto,
    size: 320,
    gapless: false,
  );
}
```

Comment: how can I encrypt with a key I have in the Login call (before where I am now)

Comment: You could use the package https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt

Comment: I crypto it and then generate the qr with the function you wrote me?